# Does data normalization reduce over-fitting when training a model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

If your training data is not normal, would normalizing it improve model fitting? How would this model (typically) perform on a testing set that is similarly not normalized?

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing a dataset is usually a good idea because some algorithms can be sensitive to ranges of values like PCA for example. If you have a feature "age" ranging from 0 to 100 for example and "price" from 10000 to 1000000, the second feature will weight more for the prediction while it might not be the most relevant. Normalizing will ensure that for each feature the values are contained in a range of the same order of magnitude. As a result it will help your model give better predictions. You should also normalize your testing set. Be sure to do this with the normalization values from the training set to avoid data leakage.